# How to print each array element on a new row

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, innerhtml

I am getting a new array element from an input and adding to array but I can not print every element in a new row. I can print all elements of array in one row but can not print every element in a different row. I am using `<br>` after array name but does not work. What is your solution? It is like a todo list project.

```js
var allmembers = [""];

function addnewmember() {
  var newmemberr = document.getElementById("newmember").value;

  allmembers.push(newmemberr);

  for (var i = 0; i < allmembers.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("membername").innerHTML = allmembers[i] + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input id="newmember" placeholder="NEW MEMBER"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="addnewmember()">SEND</button>
  <div id="members">MEMBERS</div>
  <div id="membername"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is appending a `<br>` to the end of the array, rather than between array items. Instead of looping over the array, just use the [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, which is ideal for something like this.

Additionally, using `innerHTML` in a loop is a big performance "no no" as it causes the browser to have to repaint and possibly reflow the DOM document repeatedly. In such cases, you should build up a string that contains the HTML you want and after the loop is done set that string as the `innerHTML` of the desired element in one single command. And really, the use of `innerHTML` should be avoided if at all possible because of [security concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations) as well.

See additional comments inline:

```js
let allmembers = [];

// Get your DOM references just once, not every time the function runs
// Make references to DOM elements, rather than their propreties. This
// way, if you decide you need access to a different DOM element property
// you don't have to scan for the element again.
let newmember = document.getElementById("newmember");
let memberName =  document.getElementById("membername");

function addnewmember() {
  allmembers.push(newmember.value);
  newmember.value = "";  // Clear out the input
  
  // No need for a loop. Just join the arry elements
  // with a <br> between them.
  memberName.innerHTML = allmembers.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input id="newmember" placeholder="NEW MEMBER"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="addnewmember()">SEND</button>
  <div id="members">MEMBERS</div>
  <div id="membername"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I am now reading comments and trying to understand logic.